Deploying a Model To AWS SageMaker
When attempting to create an endpoint from a model that I had created using a docker container I had deployed to ECR, I am encountering the following error:
The primary container for production variant default-variant-name did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint.

How to debug these error messages?
Here's what my Dockerfile looks like:
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.12 as build

# Copy your pre-trained model and inference code into the container
#COPY my_model.pkl /opt/ml/model/
COPY inference.py /opt/ml/inference/
COPY requirements.txt /opt/ml/inference

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /opt/ml/inference/

# Install any necessary dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Define how to run inference
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "inference.py"]

My inference.py implements these functions:
model_fn
input_fn
predict_fn
output_fn


Please follow the example here - https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-hosting/tree/main/Bring-Your-Own-Container/BYOC-Single-Model
